# Character Picker stopped working in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, internationalization

Character picker inexplicably stopped working tonight in OS X Lion.  I was trying to type in Spanish but now the keys which used to accept tildes or accents are merely repeating.

I tried entering the following command in Terminal and restarting my MacBook Air, but it didn't restore the Character Picker:

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool TRUE`

I also checked which keyboard I am using for input.  I am still using the U.S. keyboard, and that hasn't changed.

I tried logging out, restarting, and shutting down.

Is there anything else I can do to restore Character Picker?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling it.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool FALSE
```

Then reboot. If you want to reverse this change, you can enter the following to change the feature back to be enabled.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool TRUE
```