# How do I re-enable the Press and Hold character picker on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal

I disabled the character picker by [reading this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/character-picker-stopped-working-in-os-x-lion), but I want to remove that change and restore the picker.

When I type `-g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` into Terminal, it does not work.

How can I re-enable the Press & Hold character picker after disabling it?

Answer (score 9):

The command to enable the Press & Hold character picker is as follows:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

<sup>Note the addition of `defaults write` which was missing from your command.</sup>

---

If it does not work in certain apps after performing this, restart/reload those apps (e.g. `killall -HUP Finder`). Alternatively, log out of your user or just reboot your computer.

Comment: What is the difference to `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` is this also valid?

Comment: @Iony That command uses NSGlobalDomain, deprecated but currently identical to -g, and ends in ‘false’, performing the opposite function of disabling PressAndHold.

Answer (score 7):

As grgarside mentioned

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

will enable Press & Hold.  But just in case anyone comes across this, this additional command will enable the Press & Hold functionality to work in Terminal as well which it does not do by default.

```
defaults write com.apple.terminal ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago the techniques described above stopped working for me.  I tried many permutations and combinations but no luck.  I then noticed the problem seemed to be following me around, for example it was on my new Mac laptop.  Yesterday I finally figured out what was wrong: I had selected "Irish - Extended" keyboard—when I switched to just "Irish" the press-and-hold character picker started working again.  I don't know why it didn't work under "Irish - Extended", but I'm glad to have it back.