# Accented characters: hold and select has stopped working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Somehow my "press and hold" for accented characters has ceased to function.

How can I re-enable that?

Example of how it used to work is in [How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)

Comment: this might help > http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105099/10139